# Idp initiated SAML2 implementation across 2 weblogic boxes

Tags: saml-2.0, weblogic12c

We are trying to implement IdP initiated SAML2 flow for weblogic. Here is our configuration

1. PingFederate is the IdP
2. Weblogic 12c hosts our application with below configuration

   - Box a (has apps1 and apps2 in cluster) .apps1 has 19 applications deployed and apps2 has 5 applications deployed
   - Box b (has apps1 and app2 in cluster) .apps1 has 19 applications deployed and apps2 has 5 applications deployed
3. These boxes are load balanced by load balancer (F5)

We got the entire flow working with only box a running. The moment we bring up box b I am getting 403 error on the webpage for url /SAML2/ACS/POST.
Not sure if we need any additional configurations in weblogic to get this working. In help in this would be greatly appreciated as we found this issue in UAT and soon we have a prod movement planned.

Comment: reviewing https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/saml.htm#SECMG281 indicates that the Weblogic servers must be set up seperately, but identically... Are the configurations exactly the same on the same on both? What happens if you shut down box a, and use box b through the balancer?

Comment: @AndrewK.Yes the configurations on both the boxes are same. If I shut down a and access b through load balancer everything works fine.